# Extract icon from appimage

Tags: icons, shortcuts

When [creating a .desktop shortcut to an appimage](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902672/registering-appimage-files-as-a-desktop-app), the `Icon` is not automatically extracted from the appimage, even though the appimage does contain an icon.

1. Is this a limitation of the DE? Is there a bug tracking it? I'm using GNOME in Ubuntu 18.04, and forcing the user to hunt for an icon file, place it in some path, then link to it from the [`.desktop`](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en) file, is silly.
2. What's an easy way to extract the icon from that appimage?

Answer (score 21):

### 1. Automatically

There is a convenience function available for AppImages. You do not need to extract the icon manually. All you need to do is: run the optional `appimaged` daemon (it runs in user space and does not need root privileges). Download it here:

- [github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases](https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/releases) (scroll down to see it)

It's bundled as an AppImage, and can be used just like one: make it executable and execute.

This daemon scans a few well-known locations for appimages and extracts icons and creates menu entries automatically for you. (It also removes them again if you delete an AppImage).

It is recommended to keep all your AppImages in a directory you should create: *`${HOME}/AppImages`*

---

***Update:*** According to a comment by user @TSr, `appimaged` is deprecated now. I did not check this info.

### 2. Manually

If you insist to do this manually, you can run (in a terminal!):

```
 ./your.AppImage --appimage-extract
```

This will create a sub-directory called *`squashfs-root`* and extract the *complete* contents of the bundle there. Here you should find what you are looking for.

**Warning:** this will only work if the AppImage is of type 2 (following the newer AppImage spec). For AppImage type 1, you have to mount the AppImage manually and then copy the icon file from the mounted directory tree:

```
mkdir /tmp/mountpoint
sudo mount -o loop your.AppImage /tmp/mountpoint
```

---

If the icon is missing, the packager of the AppImage did not bother to include it. Complain with him/her then.

Comment: Here is a how to for the installation: https://github.com/AppImage/appimaged

Comment: appimaged is deprecated now.

Comment: `appimaged` is alive again, now at https://github.com/probonopd/go-appimage/releases/

Comment: i would reccomend keeping appimages in `${HOME}/.local/bin`, this path is standard in the user's $PATH on ubuntu these days so you won't need to mess with it and you don't need to worry about the path to a particular appimage; you can launch it like you do any other installed program

Answer (score 3):

Use AppImageLauncher, works perfect with Ubuntu 20.04: https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher

Answer (score 0):

Better to do it manually, because I have found many appimages that AppImageLauncher cannot integrate properly. Some Appimages' icons are not showing correctly as the icon is not put in the standard location where AppImageLauncher can recognize them. And some AppImages have a unique way to update itself that is incompatible with AppImageLauncher like Yuzu the switch emulator which has a maintenance tool.