# How to identify which program is using a partition (and is stopping it from being un-mounted)?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, umount

Only one partition cannot be unmounted (on other drive than the one the system is installed on) . It is also the only ext4 partition on that drive, the other two are ntfs.

[image]

I am using dual boot, have rebooted to fully shut down Windows, all partitions other than the system-running one are unmounted.

In Dolphin it says some app is using the partition

[image]

which one could that be? (Dropbox and such are shut too)

Comment: `lsof | grep /media/cip/DEPO`  will tell you

Comment: @Rinzwind - Solved as said above. As this doesn't seem a duplicate, could you post as an answer or should I ? - Reboot was needed after changing location of appimages.

Comment: you go for it :=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on Rizwind's comment: in order to see which program is accessing the partition, `lsof | grep /path/to/partition`.

(In this case appimage programs administered by `AppImageLauncherSettings` were the culprits. Moving them to another location solved this after reboot.)