# Joplin app requires two clicks in dash to open

Tags: .desktop, appimage

I've installed [Joplin](https://joplinapp.org/) via an AppImage. When I click the app in the dash, it takes two clicks for it to open. Once it's opened, if I close it and reopen it, it only takes one click.

I'm not sure why it's doing this. I suspect it's because I used [appimaged](https://askubuntu.com/a/935249/395029) to install it, which may not be initialising until the app is clicked once. And then on the second click, the app actually launches.

How am I supposed to debug this? appimaged is installed, so I don't know what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Joplin as a startup application and turning on the "Start application minimised in the tray icon" option fixed it for me.