# How do I Install appimage and .run files system wide (similar to on Manjaro)?

Tags: kubuntu, 21.04

In Manjaro if I downloaded an app image or .run (it was a game), it gave me the option to install it system wide.

How do I accomplish that on my Kubuntu 21.04?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registering AppImage Files as a desktop app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902672/registering-appimage-files-as-a-desktop-app)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have to put the binary file into a location that everyone can see.  Assuming that you have already marked the file as executable, you could put the file into /usr/local/bin with a command like

`sudo cp <path to appimage file> /usr/local/bin/`

The .run files are a little harder, as you will have to determine what they are doing, before you can make them available system wide.  This can vary from file to file.

Comment: Will add a mess to the system. The `/usr/local/bin` will be better place!