# How can I integrate AppImages into my Kubuntu 20.10 system?

Tags: kubuntu, 20.10, appimage

I have downloaded an AppImage for Logseq. I am having to open Dolphin each time I want to launch the app, which is becoming a real friction point. What's the recommended way to integrate it into my system? I'd love to have the app's icon in Plank, so it's easy for me to launch.

I've looked at some of the previous questions but they're either not for Kubuntu or a tad old. I'm running Kubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Registering AppImage Files as a desktop app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902672/registering-appimage-files-as-a-desktop-app)

Answer (score 0):

I created a Desktop Entry `logseq.desktop` and saved it into the `/usr/share/applications folder`:

```
[Desktop Entry]  
Name=Logseq  
GenericName=Personal Knowledge Manager  
Comment=A privacy-first outliner notebook for organizing and sharing your personal knowledge base and collaboration.  
Exec=/home/username/Logseq/Logseq-linux-x64-0.6.7.AppImage  
Icon=/home/username/Logseq/icon.png  
Terminal=false  
Type=Application  
MimeType=  
Categories=Office;  
Keywords=PKM  
StartupWMClass=
```

After that, I open the application launcher and search for logseq. You can also  pin it to the task manager or add it to the desktop.