# What is the best way of automaticaly integrating .AppImages with Gnome?

Tags: gnome, appimage

Or should it be done at all?

My current workflow is downloading the `.AppImages` to a repository (`~/Applications`) and run them from the command line, I would like to integrate the `.AppImages` with gnome, but there doesn´t seem to exist an obvious way of doing it.

I found out that there is a daemon for it ([appimaged](https://github.com/AppImage/appimaged)) but it doesn´t seem to be supported anymore. The site points to an [alternative codebase](https://github.com/probonopd/go-appimage) but it is not clear (at least to me) if it is stable or not. There is also [AppImageLauncher](https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher) which seems to do the trick, but it is not also clear how stable it is, once it is not endorsed by the developers of AppImage on their website.

I am aware of the manual creation of `.desktop` entries (see [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)) in order to integrate it manually (as sugested by [pLumo](https://askubuntu.com/users/631600/plumo)), but it would be nice if there is an automatic way of doing it. There is also an [older discussion on the topic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/902672/registering-appimage-files-as-a-desktop-app), but some of the answers are outdated (citing appimaged) and they do not point which one is the best alternative for doing this task.

Comment: As a workaround, manually create .desktop files and save them in `~/.local/share/applications`

Comment: @pLumo The advice in the page you pointed is usefull, but the solutions are not exactly tailored to AppImages (for instance, there is no easy way of getting icons for the AppImages). Also, most of the answers are outdated. I think there is still space for this specific question.

Comment: @pietro_molina I pointed to a duplicate on using Appimagelauncher. This is a tool that automates appimage inegration (and it even can be used as an appimage itself). A negative point of this question is that it is written as a question requiring an "opinion based" answer, still I did not vote closing for that reason.

Comment: @vanadium I also came across this question, but I was affraid the answers were a bit outdated. I reformulated my question to not require an opinion-based answer. Do you think it is enough to keep this question relevant?

Comment: Still, the answer is in the question I marked as duplicate. AppImageLauncher is actively maintained and goes as far in automation as you could imagine.

Comment: Indeed, I believe you are right, thanks for the patience, as you can see I am new to the community.