# Custom icon not displaying for AppImage

Tags: icons

I can run the appimage fine with the .desktop file but the icon does not show. I have resized it to 64x64 as well to check it wasn't a size issue. This is my .desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Appium Inspector
Comment=Android app inspector
GenericName=Developer tool
Exec=/home/kieran/Applications/Appium-Inspector.AppImage
Icon=/usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/appium.png
Type=Application;
StartupNotify=true
```

I have also run sudo update-icon-caches /usr/share/icons/* and it still appears blank.

The icon isn't even the grey cog one, it just appears blank. I'm running ubuntu 21.10.
[image]

Desktop icon appears normally, but application opens into its own icon. Is this expected?

[image]

Comment: Try AppImageLauncher instead of bicycle. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1125304/66509 .

Comment: Thanks so much, not only did it pull an icon file from somewhere else, I was able to change it to a custom one as well from the ~/.local/share/applications folder. However the application opens into it's own icon, is there anyway for it to open with the icon I have set, or is the icon in my favourites just a launcher for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To associate the running application with your `.desktop` launcher, you will need to explicitly set the `StartupWMClass` value to the WMClass of your application.

Run the application and determine its wmclass as follows. With Ubuntu 21.10 on Wayland, open the Gnome Shell looking glass by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+F2. On the "Windows" tab, find the wmclass. When running Xorg, you can use the `xprop`tool. Run the command `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` then click the window of your application.

Then edit the `.desktop`launcher and add or edit the line

```
StartupWMClass=<wmclass>
```

so it indicates the wmclass you found.

Comment: so long for linux as a desktop os: where am I supposed to find the .desktop launcher?