# How to create a `.desktop` launcher for the latest FreeCAD AppImage in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, .desktop, appimage

I can't seem to create a `.desktop` launcher for the latest FreeCAD AppImage.

I first tried [answer by @UriHerrera](https://askubuntu.com/a/1328529/541417) but it did not work. Then I included the [answer by @vanadium](https://askubuntu.com/a/1380718/541417) but it did not work too. When I press `Super+A` keys, I can't see the FreeCAD icon there. Neither does FreeCad icon appears when I pressed the `Super` key and typed `Freecad` in search bar. I also tried refreshing gnome-shell by pressing `Alt+F2`followed by pressing `r` and `Enter` but this action did not help either.

Can you tell me my mistake?

Summarising my actions:

1. I downloaded `FreeCAD-0.20`  from https://www.freecadweb.org/index.php into `~/.local/bin`.
2. Executed:

   ```
    $ chmod +x ~/.local/bin/FreeCAD-0.20.0-Linux-x86_64.AppImage
    $ ~/.local/bin/FreeCAD-0.20.0-Linux-x86_64.AppImage --appimage-extract
    $ cp ~/.local/bin/squashfs-root/freecad_weekly.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/freecad_weekly.desktop
    $ mkdir ~/.local/share/icons/FreeCAD/
    $ cp ~/.local/bin/squashfs-root/freecad_weekly.svg ~/.local/share/icons/FreeCAD/freecad_weekly.svg
    $ xprop | grep WM_CLASS
    WM_CLASS(STRING) = "gnome-terminal-server", "Gnome-terminal"
    $ gedit ~/.local/share/applications/freecad_weekly.desktop
   ```
3. Changed

   ```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Name=FreeCAD Weekly
    Exec=AppRun
    Icon=freecad_weekly
    Type=Application
    Categories=Engineering;
    Comment=Feature based Parametric Modeler
    Terminal=false
    StartupNotify=true
    NoDisplay=false
    MimeType=application/x-extension-fcstd;
   ```

   to

   ```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Name=FreeCAD Weekly
    Exec=$HOME/.local/bin/FreeCAD-0.20.0-Linux-x86_64.AppImage
    Icon=$HOME/.local/share/icons/FreeCAD/freecad_weekly.svg
    StartupWMClass="gnome-terminal-server","Gnome-terminal"
    Type=Application
    Categories=Engineering;
    Comment=Feature based Parametric Modeler
    Terminal=false
    StartupNotify=true
    NoDisplay=false
    MimeType=application/x-extension-fcstd;
   ```

Also tried `StartupWMClass=gnome-terminal-server Gnome-terminal` but this did not work too.

**Update:** Why does the Freecad icon not show properly?
[image: freecad icon not showing]

Outcome from updating `~/.local/share/applications/freecad_weekly.desktop` to:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=FreeCAD Weekly
Exec=freecad
Icon=freecad_weekly
Type=Application
Categories=Engineering;
Comment=Feature based Parametric Modeler
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
NoDisplay=false
MimeType=application/x-extension-fcstd;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there. Replace `$HOME` by the actual pathname. `.desktop` files do not know about bash variables.

Tips:

- You can leave out the path names. Since `~/.local/bin` is in your path, and `.local/share/icons` is a location where icons are searched, it is sufficient to just mention the file name of the executable, i.e., `Exec=FreeCAD-0.20.0-Linux-x86_64.AppImage` and the file name of the icon *without* the extension, i.e.,  `Icon=freecad_weekly`.
- Personally, I would rather place the AppImage file in a directory "~/.apps" and create a symlink to it in `~/.local/bin`, e.g. `ln -s ~/.apps/FreeCAD-0.20.0-Linux-x86_64.AppImage ~/.local/bin/freecad`. The line now becomes `Exec=freecad`. That way you can

  1. Run the program conveniently from the terminal using the command `freecad`.
  2. When you later download an updated appimage, it will be sufficient to recreate the link to have it point to the new version.

Comment: Thanks. I have attached to my question an imaged of the freecad icon which is not showing correctly. Why is this so?

Comment: Also, with or without `StartupWMClass="gnome-terminal-server","Gnome-terminal"`, the "freecad" icon appears. Is this statement still needed?

Comment: Since I am not on your system, I cannot verify whether the icon is a valid graphics file and whether it effectively is in a correct location. Perhaps the icon file needs to be right under ~/.local/share/icons/ for it to work with the name alone (although systemwide once certainly can have subdirs).

Comment: You are right. The icon file needs to be right inside `~/.local/share/icons/` and not inside a subdir. I should have done `$ cp ~/.app/squashfs-root/freecad_weekly.svg ~/.local/share/icons/freecad_weekly.svg`.