# appimage from Dolphin: "launching executables is not allowed in this context"

Tags: kubuntu, kde, dolphin

Kubuntu 21.04 - When trying to run an appimage from Dolphin, I get

```
For security reasons, launching executables is not allowed in this context
```

The permissions are set correctly. It works if I right-click and "Run in Konsole", or if I minimize everything and run it from the desktop. PCManFM will run it, putting up a similar message but offering the option to run the program anyway. I can also "trust" the application and it just runs, now.

So what's up with Dolphin? What security reasons? What context? Is it possible to run an appimage from Dolphin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is up with Dolphin and the AppImage. It is rather your desktop environment that has some security measures in place. Increasingly, the possibility of running any random file just by just double-clicking in the file manager is being deprecated. It is not allowed from within Dolphin. It is still allowed, however, from the desktop.

Start the AppImage in one of the supported ways. Better yet, [create a  `.desktop` launcher](https://askubuntu.com/a/907572/558158) for the AppImage so you can start it from the application menu like any other program. Alternatively, a tool [AppImageLauncher](https://askubuntu.com/a/1125304/558158) is available that can automate that process.

Comment: This is answer is factually wrong. In fact, on a technical basis, it doesn't really even make much sense for the DE to forbid a user application from executing code or spawning new processes— Doing so would break most applications in existence. See @Svrbisha's answer. The issue is just Dolphin configuration, under "General"→"Confirmations"→"When opening an executable file", silently forbidding all executables when set to not auto-run scripts.

Answer (score 5):

1. open Dolphin
2. settings
3. configure
4. configure Dolphin
5. General
6. confirmations
7. set "when opening an executible file" to "run script"
8. done :)

Comment: This is the right answer. If you have it set to "Open In Application", then Dolphin just outright forbids you from executing files. However, "Always Ask" is probably the more sensible option than "Run Script" IMO.